# Issues with compiling multiple files

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

So I'm trying to write a bit of code to work with sudoku puzzles, and I keep getting errors when I try to compile, and each time i compile it deletes the driver.

heres the code for the driver:

```
/*
 * Jared C
 * C++ Project
 */
#include <iostream>
#include "SudokuBoard.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SudokuBoard board("sudoku.txt");
    board.printBoard();
}
```

And here's the header file

```
/*
 * Jared C
 * SudokuBoard.h
 */

#ifndef __SUDOKUBOARD_H_INCLUDED__ 
#define __SUDOKUBOARD_H_INCLUDED__  

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class SudokuBoard
{
  private:
    int content[9][9];

  public:
    SudokuBoard(std::string filename);
    void printBoard();
    int getNumAt(int, int);
    void setNumAt(int, int, int);
};

#endif
```

And finally the Sudoku Board.cpp

```
/*
 * Jared C
 * SudokuBoard.cpp
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "SudokuBoard.h"


using namespace std;

SudokuBoard::SudokuBoard(string filename)
{
    string output;
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline (file, line))
        {
            output += line;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else cout<< "unable to open file" << endl;
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            content[x][y] = atoi(output.substr(count,1).c_str());
            count ++;
        }
    }
}

void SudokuBoard::printBoard()
{
    string output = "\n";

    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        if(y%3==0)
        {
            output += '\n';
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            if(x%3==0)
            {
                output += " ";
            }
            output += content[x][y];
            output += "\n";
        }
    }
    cout<<output<<endl;
}

int SudokuBoard::getNumAt(int x, int y)
{
    return content[x][y];
}

void SudokuBoard::setNumAt(int x, int y, int value)
{
    content[x][y] = value;
}
```

When i call `gcc -c SudokuBoard.cpp` I get the SudokuBoard.o file just fine, but when I then call 'gcc -o Driver.cpp SudokuBoard.o' I get a huge wall of error messages, heres a sample of them:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11


SudokuBoard.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
SudokuBoard.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
```

And it deletes Driver.cpp Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Re `__SUDOKUBOARD_H_INCLUDED__ `, identifiers with two successive underscores are reserved to the implementation, so this is formal UB.

Comment: why not choose an answer that *solves your problem* as a solution? it's not very nice to readers to choose one that doesn't work. that's like active misdirection. there are two answers that work. i suggest you choose one of them.

Comment: The solution I selected as correct worked perfectly for me, that's why I selected it.

Comment: Here on my computer it produced the wall of errors you complained about. It also did that on your computer.

Comment: Try making a build directory with all the .cpp and .h files in it, and then `cd` to the build directory, and try running `g++ *.cpp -o Sudoku` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the -o option with gcc is used for specifying the output file. If you write

```
gcc -o Driver.cpp SudokuBoard.o
```

you tell the compiler to create an executable file named Driver.cpp out of the object file SudokuBoard.o. But as SudokuBoard.o has no main method, this will fail, therefore the error messages.
Try

```
gcc -c SudokuBoard.cpp
gcc -c Driver.cpp
gcc -o Sudoku SudokuBoard.o Driver.o
```

instead.

Comment: Last line there should be `gcc -o sudoku Sudokuboard.o Driver.o` right? And you normally want to use `g++`, not `gcc` for C++ code.

Comment: @harald: Yes, you're right, I forgot the output file myself. Just edited my answer; should be correct now.

Comment: This does not address the issue of linking errors, only the "And it deletes Driver.cpp". It is a good idea to **try out** your solution before posting it.

Comment: **−1** because this doesn't solve the problem of wall of error messages, and has been selected by the OP as solution, so it needs a little counter-weight in order to not mislead.

Answer (score 4):

Your command line is incorrect:

```
gcc -o Driver.cpp SudokuBoard.o
```

Instructs `gcc` to link the object file SudokuBoard.o as an executable file named `Driver.cpp`.  No surprise that it first erases the destination file.

Furthermore, you do not specify the runtime library to link with and `gcc` does not default to C++: this explains the error message.

You should instead write:

```
g++ -o Sudoku Driver.o SudokuBoard.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `g++` to compile C++ code, not the common C-oriented `gcc`.

`g++` invokes `gcc` for compilation and linking with the right options for C++.

In short, it's a good idea to use a C++ compiler for C++ source code, a Fortran compiler for Fortran source code, and so on.

---

Also, for the issue of “And it deletes Driver.cpp”, simply don't specify that source file as an output file.

Comment: No actually.  Downvote due to your post having the same issue for which you are downvoting others.  In other words, you are holding other members to a standard to which you do not hold yourself.

Comment: @Peter: you need to **try out** your suggested commands. they reproduce the wall of errors. this answer, OTOH, is correct. And so is chqrlie's answer. Tim's answer has just been fixed, but it's not as complete as this and chqrlie's answer.

Comment: You're confusing me with someone else, Alf.   I did not suggest any commands, so had no need to try any out.   I interpret your down-voting as being about downvoting other answers with similarity to your own.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you it can't find the implementation for `std::basic_string<...>`.

You need to tell the compiler how to find the compiled code for `std::basic_string<...>`. Much how with your own code, if you tried to build an executable out of just `Driver.cpp` the compiler would complain about missing `SudokuBoard` references until you told it about `SudokuBoard.o`.

In this case you need to tell the compiler about the C++ standard library. This library are usually shipped with your distribution. On Windows in the form of `dll` files, on OS X `dylib` files and on Linux `so` files. Conceptually they are similar, many bags of `.o` files all together. Either way, you tell the linker to link to the C++ standard library.

`gcc` calls the C++ standard library `libstdc++`, so your command would be something like: `gcc -o Driver Driver.cpp SudokuBoard.o -lstdc++`.

Comment: Instead of the "something like", why did you not just advise to use g++?